# no puedo acceder carpeta imagenes class library

Tags: c#, net, .netframework

, cuando la uso desde otro proyecto en este caso un proyecto web api , desde la liberia uso esta linea de codigoHttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@ y se me para en el proyecto web api , y no me deja subir un nivel ,  y  no puedo acceder a la carpeta  imagenes de la class library .

el error que me tira es este Message": "Error.", "ExceptionMessage": "No se puede utilizar .. inicial para salir por encima del directorio superior.".

el codigo de la class library es este para obtener la ruta de una imagen que uso dentro de la libreria es.

```
public static string ObtenerRutaImagen()

{

string path = string.Empty;

//no es web

   
path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rutaImagen"];

}

else // si es web le doy la ruta relativa.

{

string relativeImagePath = @"CAUtilidades\img\Cabecera.png";

path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/../+ relativeImagePath);



}

return path;

}
```

les queria consultar si sigo por este camino o tienen alguna sugerencia o otra opcion forma de hacerlo mejor.
gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si la los recursos se encuentran dentro del assembly (de tu librería de clases), deberias poder compartirlo como un recurso ("resource") de dicha libreria y no como una carpeta. Es decir que la librería sea quien comparta dicho recurso y no que se acceda directamente "buscando en carpetas" (por mas que se pueda). Ademas, si se comparte la ubicacion de dicho archivo deberia ser por la gestion de recursos de dicho assembly. Para que realmente este "encapsulado". Es decir hay una forma de que el contenido este "visible" en las carpetas del proyecto (por ejemplo si se comparte como "Contenido/Content" dicho recurso en las [Build Actions/Acciones de compilación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022)), pero deberia ser responsabiliad de dicha librería brindartelo, y a lo sumo que la app contenedora (la que utiliza la libreria, enviar el path de ubicacion que puede diferer por el tipo de prouyecto console, web, etc.)

Resumiendo, pudes compartir de dos formas los recursos (texto, imagenes, etc.) para tu proyecto o librerias

- OPCION 1: Creas una carpeta en algun lugar comun (storage compartido, repositorio de acceso. Pero esto ya seria fuera de la libreria de clases. Como tener una carpeta de "assets", recursos por fuera del proyecto (y configuras el path por web.config, appSettings, db, parametro de enviroment, etc)
- OPCION 2: Utilizas la libreria de clases para "compartir el recurso". Es util porque va o embebido en assembly y es facil de "empaquetarlo" para la redistribucion... y aquí se despendren varias opciones para agregarlo al recurso.

Para la opcion 2, dejo mas abajo un repo con ejemplos   https://github.com/fernandezja/retrieve-resources-dotnet

Como lo presentas a tu ejemplo así:

> Tengo una class library en netframework 4.8 y tengo una carpeta
> imagenes dentro de este proyecto class library que lo uso para generar
> pdf,excel

Entonces, debería ser que dicha librería comparta y sea la que brinde estos recursos a los que necesiten.

En .NET Framework tiene la posibilidad de utilizar varias formas, las mas habituales (por lo menos de los proyectos que participe) son:

- Crear en dicha libreria [un archivo de recursos, .resx, pero tienes otras oopciones](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/extensions/create-resource-files), pero con .resx va generando codigo para "exponerlo" (tienes que indicar que sob recursos "publicos" para exponerlos).
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Agregar recurso (archivo de texto, imagen, etc.) a la librería y cambiar la [Build Actions/Acciones de compilación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022) para poder indicar si es un Contenido (Content) o Recurso Embebido (Embedded Resource)
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Textual de Microsoft Learn de cada "accion":

> **Contenido (Content)**: Un archivo marcado como Contenido se puede recuperar como un flujo mediante una llamada a Application.GetContentStream. En proyectos de ASP.NET, estos archivos se incluyen como parte del sitio cuando se implementa..

> **Recurso Embebido (Embedded Resource):** El archivo se pasa al compilador de C# como un recurso que se va a insertar en el ensamblado. Puede llamar a System.Reflection.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream para leer el archivo del ensamblado.

Para que puedas tener un ejemplo, genere este repositorio con recursos dentro de una librería, donde se obtiene mediante test (para que sea facil de que puedas ver el ejemplo) y desde una app de consola o mvc. Lo pudes ver desde este repositorio:

- Repo: **retrieve-resources-dotnet** | Retrieve resources from assemblies (string, file, image, etc.) use resources files, and build action content and embedded https://github.com/fernandezja/retrieve-resources-dotnet

Dale una mirada al ejemplo para que puedas exponer de algunas de estas formas dichos "recursos".

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda o guía:

- [Creación de archivos de recursos para aplicaciones .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/extensions/create-resource-files)
- [Build Actions/Acciones de compilación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Muchas Gracias Jose A. Fernandez muy buena info.  y con ejemplo y todo